# Calculated value presented as a Response Time in JMeter report

Tags: jmeter

There is a system, where entities change their statuses over time.

I am creating a JMeter test measuring the time passed between 2 subsequent statuses.

There seems to be no straight-forward way to include this information into the report.

So far I tried the `BeanShell Sampler` which accepts timestamps as arguments and creates a `SampleResult`:

```
long start = Long.parseLong(vars.get("containerCreatedTime"));
long end = Long.parseLong(vars.get("containerStartedTime"));
SampleResult.createTestSample(start, end);
```

OR simply calculating the delta (this one just puts the value to the 'Response data' - doesn't influence the report):

```
Long.parseLong(vars.get("containerStartedTime")) - Long.parseLong(vars.get("containerCreatedTime"));
```

No luck with any of these approaches.

What I basically need is to adjust the Sample Time (Response Time) of the Sampler with the calculated value.

I'm new to JMeter with too few tools in the toolbox. Could anyone suggest ways to achieve the goal? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since JMeter 3.1 [it is recommended to use Groovy for any form of scripting in JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider switching to JSR223 elements.

If you need to modify Sampler's response time I would recommend doing it via [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor)

1. Add JSR223 PostProcessor as a child of the Sampler, which response time you want to modify
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def delta = (vars.get('containerStartedTime') as long) - (vars.get("containerCreatedTime") as long)
   java.lang.reflect.Field elapsed = prev.getClass().getDeclaredField('elapsedTime')
   elapsed.setAccessible(true)
   elapsed.set(prev, delta)
   ```

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more details on using Groovy scripting in JMeter tests.